# How to display current Windows OS date, time and timezone in CLI?

Tags: window

In Linux, printing out date, time, and timezone can be easily accomplished with `date` command

```
[user@linux ~]$ date
Sun Mar 10 11:51:55 -04 2018
[user@linux ~]$
```

`-4` before after the time and before the year represents timezone (-4).

This is in Python ....

```
[user@linux ~]$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May  3 2017, 07:55:04) 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import time
>>> print (time.strftime("\n Date: %d %B %Y, %H:%M:%S %Z\n"))

 Date: 11 March 2018, 00:05:50 EST

>>>
```

I was wondering how to perform the same thing on Windows OS using native windows command?

`echo  %date%-%time%` command can only produce day, date, dan time. However timezone is not there.

```
C:\> echo  %date%-%time%
 Sun 03/10/2018-11:56:05.31

C:\>
```

What I'm expecting is something like this.

```
C:\> <some windows command>
 Sun Mar 10 11:51:55 -04 2018

C:\>
```

or

```
C:\> <some windows command>
Date: 11 March 2018, 00:05:50 EST

C:\>
```

Comment: Just a small FYI, but [Python is available for Windows](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/)

Comment: I'm aware of that. My question was how to do it using Windows native command

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use this to output the current date, time, and time zone:

```
echo %date% %time% & tzutil /g
```

Or if you want to output them in a single line:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %i in ('tzutil /g') do echo %date% %time% %i
```

Take note that you need to change `%i` to `%%i` if you want to put them in a batch file.