# Get timezone from windows command line

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

Query the time zone from the command line I want to print the a bottom line with the echo command

this is my try but i get the error

```
@echo off
set a="tzutil /g" 
echo %a%
exit
```

please help

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/1302362/how-to-display-current-windows-os-date-time-and-timezone-in-cli

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display current Windows OS date, time and timezone in CLI?](https://superuser.com/questions/1302362/how-to-display-current-windows-os-date-time-and-timezone-in-cli)

Comment: why change the accepted answer?

Comment: it was no problem - was just wondering why you would accept my answer then accept a different answer that says basically the same thing but was added later. (only one can be accepted.)

Comment: what i needed was your answer

Comment: you use the checkmark to accept only one answer; you can upvote as many as you like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### How can I print the timezone from a batch file using `echo`?

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('tzutil /g') do (
  echo %%f
  )
endlocal
```

Example usage:

```
F:\test>test
GMT Standard Time

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [For /f- Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- [tzutil - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/tzutil.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to echo the time zone, all you need is:

```
@echo off

tzutil /g
echo.

pause
```

Unless you want to have quotes *inside* your variable, you want to put them before and after your set options like this: `set "zone=tzutil /g"` instead of having your first double quote *after* the equals sign. If your goal is to set the output of `tzutil /g` as a variable, you would do it like this:

```
@echo off

for /f "tokens=* usebackq" %%A in (`tzutil /g`) do (
    set "zone=%%A"
)

echo %zone%

pause
```

Here you use `for /f` to loop through the output of a command, then set your variable using the parameter.

Reference: [tzutil](https://ss64.com/nt/tzutil.html), [For /f](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)